# Python- Code not retaining variable assigned in definition

Tags: python, definition

I am trying to create a card game but I am having trouble with definitions. In particular, the definition below, should return a shuffled deck (no suits yet) under the variable 'deck'. However, I receive the error:

> NameError: 'name 'deck' is not defined.

I can avoid this by not using definitions, however, I want to have as much as possible in definitions to make it easier in the long run. Thanks in advance.

```
import random
playerhand=[]
dealerhand=[]

def shuffle():
    numbers = []
    faces = ['T', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']
    for i in range(8):
        numb = str(i + 2)
        numbers.append(numb)
    values=numbers+faces
    deck=4*values
    random.shuffle(deck)
    return deck

print deck[0]
```

Comment: That's not how return values work. You need to call your function `shuffle`, which will return the value that `deck` held. `deck` is only available within the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two points:

1. You're defining a function but are not calling it. If you don't call a function, the code inside it doesn't get executed.
2. The variable called `deck` is local to the function and disappears the moment the function returns.

Here is one way to solve both problems at once:

```
def shuffle():
    ...
    deck = ...
    ...
    return deck

deck = shuffle()
print deck[0]
```

Just to be clear, there are two variables here that both happen to be called `deck` and should not be confused with each other. To make this distinction clear, in the following I've given them different names:

```
def shuffle():
    ...
    local_deck = ...
    ...
    return local_deck

global_deck = shuffle()
print global_deck[0]
```

The two code snippets are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

The 'deck' variable is locally defined in your function. So you can't use it outside of the function definition. Since your function returns deck, use

```
print shuffle()[0] # this is outside of the function scope
```

instead

Answer (score 0):

`deck` is only in scope within `shuffle`. To access the value that shuffle returns, call `shuffle`, then use it's return value:

```
import random
playerhand=[]
dealerhand=[]

def shuffle():
    numbers = []
    faces = ['T', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']
    for i in range(8):
        numb = str(i + 2)
        numbers.append(numb)
    values=numbers+faces
    deck=4*values
    random.shuffle(deck)
    return deck

print shuffle()
```

I think you're progressing too quickly if you made this mistake though. Read more about variable scoping, calling functions, and the `return` statement. Covering all that here would be far too long.

Answer (score 0):

When you `return` a value from a function, it sets the value **of that function** to the value you returned

*i.e.* in this example,`foo()` would equal 4, therefore 8 would be printed

```
def foo()
    return 4

print(foo() * 2)
```

In your example, you need to change the last line to `print(shuffle()[0])`, and your code will work as expected.